# DisplayAlert not showing on Xamarin forms ios only

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

For some reason the displayalert is not showing when i navigate from one page to another on ios only. it works on android though. Here is simple code

```
//Navigating to other page
Navigation.PushAsync(new page1());

//Page1 Code

public page1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   DisplayAlert("Test", "Test Successful", "Ok");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below it will work for you

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => 
 {

  DisplayAlert("Test", "Test Successful", "Ok");

 });
```

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/

Answer (score 0):

Another variant - call DisplayAlert from current MainPage.

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Test", "Test Successful", "Ок");
```